# Postgres table partitioning "no partition of relation "parsel_part" found for row" error?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, postgresql-10

I'm trying to use new partitioning method of PostgreSQL 10. I have a parent table that contains 1.5 million rows. I want to create partitioning on this already populated table.

I've created a  **new master** table which has identical columns with **real master** table from the CREATE SCRIPT;

```
CREATE TABLE master_part (objectid integer,poly geometry(Geometry,2321), parcel character varying(255), m_date(date)) PARTITION BY RANGE (m_date);
```

Then I've created child tables, partitioned by the m_date column;

```
CREATE TABLE parsel_2014_04
  PARTITION OF parsel_part FOR VALUES FROM ('2014-04-01') TO ('2014-04-30');

CREATE TABLE parsel_2014_05
      PARTITION OF parsel_part FOR VALUES FROM ('2014-05-01') TO ('2014-05-31');

CREATE TABLE parsel_2014_06
      PARTITION OF parsel_part FOR VALUES FROM ('2014-06-01') TO ('2014-06-30');

CREATE TABLE parsel_2014_07
      PARTITION OF parsel_part FOR VALUES FROM ('2014-07-01') TO ('2014-07-31');

CREATE TABLE parsel_2014_08
      PARTITION OF parsel_part FOR VALUES FROM ('2014-08-01') TO ('2014-08-31');

CREATE TABLE parsel_2014_09
      PARTITION OF parsel_part FOR VALUES FROM ('2014-09-01') TO ('2014-09-30');

CREATE TABLE parsel_2014_10
      PARTITION OF parsel_part FOR VALUES FROM ('2014-10-01') TO ('2014-10-30');

CREATE TABLE parsel_2014_11
      PARTITION OF parsel_part FOR VALUES FROM ('2014-11-01') TO ('2014-11-30');

CREATE TABLE parsel_2014_12
      PARTITION OF parsel_part FOR VALUES FROM ('2014-12-01') TO ('2014-12-31');

CREATE TABLE parsel_2015_01
      PARTITION OF parsel_part FOR VALUES FROM ('2015-01-01') TO ('2015-01-31');

CREATE TABLE parsel_2015_02
      PARTITION OF parsel_part FOR VALUES FROM ('2015-02-01') TO ('2015-02-28');

CREATE TABLE parsel_2015_03
      PARTITION OF parsel_part FOR VALUES FROM ('2015-03-01') TO ('2015-03-31');

CREATE TABLE parsel_2015_04
      PARTITION OF parsel_part FOR VALUES FROM ('2015-04-01') TO ('2015-04-30');
```

When I run the script above to create child tables I'm getting the error below;

> ERROR:  no partition of relation "parsel_part" found for row
>   DETAIL:  Partition key of the failing row contains (m_date) = (2014-10-31).
>   SQL state: 23514

This error seems to be very rare because I couldn't find anything about it.

Maybe some one have seen it before ?

Comment: Maybe your partition for `parsel_2014_10` should run from 2014-10-01 to 2014-10-31, instead of to 2014-10-30.

Comment: I've checked the dates and tried   "2014-10-31" too.

Comment: @RDFozz no, that wouldn't work either. The `TO` bounds are exclusive. Patrick has answered.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - Mostly just pointing out that the last day of October is the 31st, not the 30th. As all the `TO` dates should presumably be the first of the next month, this does indeed become an issue one can ignore, in this case.

Comment: @RDFozz right, one more advantage of inclusive-exclusive ranges. No need to calculate how many days each month has!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your problem is related to this point in the documentation:

> When creating a range partition, the **lower** bound specified with `FROM` is an **inclusive** bound, whereas **the upper bound** specified with `TO` **is an exclusive bound**.

(emphasis added)

So in fact in

```
CREATE TABLE parsel_2014_10 PARTITION OF parsel_part 
     FOR VALUES FROM ('2014-10-01') TO ('2014-10-31');
```

the date `2014-10-31` is **not** included in this partition, and hence nowhere in all your partition tables (and same for all ending dates)

See the example at: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE

The `to` value of one partition must be the same as the `from` value of the next one (because the `to` part is exclusive and the `from` is inclusive).